# Area under the curve

Tags: definite-integrals, applications, area

suppose we have graph of $\sin(x)$ and a ellipse say $\frac{x^2}{10}+\frac{y^2}{2}=1$ it comes like following 
[image: sin]

[image: ellipse]

now when we intregrate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(x)dx$ it comes out to be zero , because area above $x$-axis is equal to area below $x$-axis so therefore when we compute area of ellipse it should also be equal to zero ? why is't it taken to be zero?

Comment: The integral gives *signed* area. Also, what's the function for the ellipse?

Comment: for half-upper part $f(x)=\sqrt{2-\frac{2x^2}{10}}$

Comment: The ellipse above can be described by two functions, say $f_1$ and $f_2 = - f_1$. The area is given by $\int (f_1-f_2) = 2 \int f_1$. For the $\sin$ function, we have $f_1 = \sin$, $f_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As The Chaz said, computing the integral gives a signed integral; so, since your ellipse is centered, the result is zero. If you move the center of the same ellipse up or down, you will get a different result.

Comment: that means i have to do what @copper.hat described above